# Difference between logical and linear address?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I've been reading the Linux -Understanding Kernel book and came across Logical addresses and Linear Addresses.I'm unable to understand the need for logical addresses.Why cant we directly access the linear address .What is the need for logical addresses and what is the use of segmentation and GDT(Global Descriptor Table) maintaining for all the processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical addressing provides several functions. Among other things:
1. They are a prerequisite for implementing virtual memory
2. During swap in/swap out they eliminate the need the process to be loaded back into the same physical memory.
3. They provide consistent addressing among process.
4. Support memory protection

Comment: but all these functions are done by linear addressing right?thats the reason linear addresses are also called virtual address.Please help

Comment: Logical addressing could be implemented without virtual memory. However, they two are normally done together. Sometimes the terms logical and virtual get conflicted.

Comment: Im still confused about this.Ca you please suggest me some reference where i can get some insight

Comment: Logical memory creates a linear address space from non-linear physical memory. Virtual memory is the process of mapping these linear addresses to disk.